# Select by style mapinfo to QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapinfo-discover

Mapinfo/Discover has a wonderful digitizing tool "select by graphical style".  Is there something equivalent in QGIS?

Comment: What does that tool do?

Comment: Say you have a layer where blue lines are creeks and red lines are rivers but neither are attributed.  You can select the blue lines (ie, by graphical style) and attribute them all in one action.

Comment: Without any distinguishing attribute you can't categorize a layer in QGIS, hence you wont have different colours within the same layer.

Comment: Thanks Eric. And so, I have a Mapinfo tab file which has a thousand blue lines, that I know are Faults, another thousand that are green that I know are bedding trend lines, a large number of brown polygons that are rock outcrops and several other categories which I won't mention, but none are annotated.  If you are correct and I'm sure you are, I will have to use Mapinfo to solve a problem that QGIS can't handle.  What would you do if you were confronted with this?

Comment: I have no idea how mapinfo works, hence I wont speculate.

Comment: if the color/or style can be an attribute value it can be used to create an expression and an action can be done when selecting.